# Removing the last element in a do-while

Tags: php

How can I remove the last element in a `do-while` generated table?

In my case the last `tr/td` where `div.dividing_line` is stored.

The code:

```
$ArrayLength = 6; 
$i = 1;
do {
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Position</td>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Item</td>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Pieces</td>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><div class="dividing_line"></div></td>
    </tr>
    ';
    ++$i;
} while ($i < $ArrayLength+1);
```

For example: If I have an array with 6 items, normally the `do-while` will do the job, so finally there will be 6 `tr`'s with data and 6 `tr`'s with the `dividing_line`.

What I need is 6 `tr`'s of data and 5 `tr`'s of `dividing_line`. Is that possible?

Comment: How did you figure this is a `foreach`? It's a `do-while`...

Comment: Excuse me please, you're right. I had another case in my foreground so i was confused! Thank you

Comment: FYI, any conditional statements can be used inside loop statements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
$ArrayLength = 6; 
$i = 1;
do {
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Position</td>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Item</td>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Pieces</td>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Price</td>
    </tr>';
   if($i != $ArrayLength) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td colspan="4"><div class="dividing_line"></div></td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
    ++$i;
} while ($i < $ArrayLength+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ArrayLength = 6; 
$i = 1;
do {
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Position</td>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Item</td>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Pieces</td>
        <td valign="middle">Data_Price</td>
    </tr>';

    if($i < $ArrayLength)
    {
        echo '
         <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><div class="dividing_line"></div></td>
        </tr>';
    }
    ++$i;
} while ($i < $ArrayLength+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an extra if Statement to check whether you are at the last element:

```
if (%i < $ArrayLength) { echo '<tr>...dividing_line</tr>'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach just needs an additional step.

It could be something like this:

```
$data = null;

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $data[] = "<tr><td valign=\"middle\">Data_Position</td><td valign=\"middle\">Data_Item</td><td valign=\"middle\">Data_Pieces</td><td valign=\"middle\">Data_Price</td></tr>";
}

print implode("<tr><td colspan=\"4\"><div class=\"dividing_line\"></div></td></tr>", $data);
```

This way, you could accomplish what you want without any more logic. Of course, it can be changed or re-design, but I think this way will provide you with a simple yet elegan solution to your problem.

Hope it helps :P

Comment: Hmmm no, sorry... didn't read the last part well. My apologies. Let me think a bit and I'll refine my answer :S